# Out of Memory Exception in Azure Function using Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio

I have a queue triggered azure function that sends emails/texts.  I use application insights to track custom events so I can monitor the number of emails, texts, errors.  Occasionally I will get out of memory exceptions when creating the Telemetry Client object.  Here is my TelemetryHandler.cs class:

```
internal class TelemetryHandler : IDisposable
{
    private const string EmailSentEvent = "Email Sent";
    private const string EmailFailedEvent = "Email Failure";
    private const string TextSentEvent = "Text Sent";
    private const string ErrorEvent = "Error";
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    private readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> properties;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, double> metrics;

    public TelemetryHandler()
    {
        telemetryConfiguration = new(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"));
        telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
        metrics = new();
        properties = new();
    }

    public void InitializeFromMessage(EmailTextMessage emailTextMessage)
    {
        properties.Add("Tenant ID", emailTextMessage.TenantID);
        properties.Add("User", emailTextMessage.User);
        properties.Add("Payload", emailTextMessage.Payload.ToString());
    }

    public void FinalizeSendEmailEvent(string messageID)
    {
        properties.Add("Postmark Message ID", messageID);
        metrics.Add("Emails", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(EmailSentEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void FinalizeSendTextEvent(string sid)
    {
        properties.Add("Twilio Message Sid", sid);
        metrics.Add("Texts", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(TextSentEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void FinalizeSendEmailFailure(string errorMessage)
    {
        properties.Add("Error Message", errorMessage);
        metrics.Add("Failed", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(EmailFailedEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void FinalizeErrorEvent(Exception ex)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new(ex.Message);
        Exception exception = ex;
        while(exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            message.Append($"{Environment.NewLine}{exception.InnerException.Message}");
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        properties.Add("Message", message.ToString());
        properties.Add("Stack Trace", ex.StackTrace);
        metrics.Add("Error", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(ErrorEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(telemetryConfiguration != null)
            telemetryConfiguration.Dispose();   
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be causing the out of memory exception and how to fix?  It occurs when there are a large number of messages waiting on the queue (say more than 15), but I have reduced the batch size down to 4.  I can't get a stack trace from the log on the error, only that it is occurring in my TelemetryHandler constructor.  I am disposing of my TelemetryHandler class at the end of the function as well (which disposes the TelemtryConfiguration object).  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about the `TelemetryClient`. You are never disposing the client?

Comment: It's not disposable

Comment: Do you create a TelemetryHandler for every upload? Or is it a singleton? If it is not you should consider creating only one TelemetryClient and passing it as a parameter.

Comment: I am testing that approach now.  I guess in that case I would never actually need to dispose of the configuration object.

Comment: @Bob, TelemetryClient definitely can be reused (it is thread-safe as well). I'll try to repro it to see whether it has to be reused.

Comment: @ZakiMa see answer below.  Appreciate your suggestion and would like to get your thoughts on the rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone with the suggestion of using my TelemetryHandler class as a singleton and using DI to pass it as a parameter.  Here is the interface and updated version of the class:

```
internal interface ITelemetryHandler
{
    void FinalizeSendEmailEvent(string tenantID, string user, EmailMessage emailMessage, string messageID);
    void FinalizeSendEmailFailure(string tenantID, string user, EmailMessage emailMessage, string errorMessage);
    void FinalizeSendTextEvent(string tenantID, string user, TextMessage textMessage, string sid);
    void FinalizeErrorEvent(EmailTextMessage emailTextMessage, Exception ex);
}
```

```
internal class TelemetryHandler : ITelemetryHandler, IDisposable
{
    private const string EmailSentEvent = "Email Sent";
    private const string EmailFailedEvent = "Email Failure";
    private const string TextSentEvent = "Text Sent";
    private const string ErrorEvent = "Error";
    private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient;
    private readonly TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration;

    public TelemetryHandler()
    {
        telemetryConfiguration = new(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"));
        telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }

    public void FinalizeSendEmailEvent(string tenantID, string user, EmailMessage emailMessage, string messageID)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> properties = new();
        Dictionary<string, double> metrics = new();
        properties.Add("Tenant ID", tenantID);
        properties.Add("User", user);
        properties.Add("Payload", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailMessage));
        properties.Add("Postmark Message ID", messageID);
        metrics.Add("Emails", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(EmailSentEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void FinalizeSendTextEvent(string tenantID, string user, TextMessage textMessage, string sid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> properties = new();
        Dictionary<string, double> metrics = new();
        properties.Add("Tenant ID", tenantID);
        properties.Add("User", user);
        properties.Add("Payload", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(textMessage));
        properties.Add("Twilio Message Sid", sid);
        metrics.Add("Texts", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(TextSentEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void FinalizeSendEmailFailure(string tenantID, string user, EmailMessage message, string errorMessage)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> properties = new();
        Dictionary<string, double> metrics = new();
        properties.Add("Tenant ID", tenantID);
        properties.Add("User", user);
        properties.Add("Payload", message.ToString());
        properties.Add("Error Message", errorMessage);
        metrics.Add("Failed", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(EmailFailedEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void FinalizeErrorEvent(EmailTextMessage emailTextMessage, Exception ex)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> properties = new();
        Dictionary<string, double> metrics = new();
        if (emailTextMessage != null)
        {
            properties.Add("Tenant ID", emailTextMessage.TenantID);
            properties.Add("User", emailTextMessage.User);
            properties.Add("Payload", emailTextMessage.Payload.ToString());
        }
        StringBuilder message = new(ex.Message);
        Exception exception = ex;
        while (exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            message.Append($"{Environment.NewLine}{exception.InnerException.Message}");
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        properties.Add("Message", message.ToString());
        properties.Add("Stack Trace", ex.StackTrace);
        metrics.Add("Error", 1);
        telemetryClient.TrackEvent(ErrorEvent, properties, metrics);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (telemetryConfiguration != null)
            telemetryConfiguration.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And here is how it is used as a singleton:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FWT.EmailText.Startup))]

namespace FWT.EmailText;

class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryHandler>((s) => {
            return new TelemetryHandler();
        });
    }
}
class EmailTextHandler
{
    private readonly ITelemetryHandler telemetryHandler;

    public EmailTextHandler(ITelemetryHandler telemetryHandler)
    {
        this.telemetryHandler = telemetryHandler;
    }

    [FunctionName("EmailTextHandler")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%QueueName%", Connection = "QueueStorageAccount")] string queueMessage, ILogger log)
    {
        //Function code that accesses telemetryHandler
    }
}
```

For anyone that might need it, I used this article to set up singleton/DI inside an azure function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection